# When trying to edit comments quick, error message pops up wrong

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, error-message

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceqEF.png]

---

### Details

- All comments disappear
- Message pops up like a comment:

  > {"success":false,"message":"You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds."}
- Reproduced on MSO and SO
- Hasn't happened for a while; just noticed now
- Possible side effect of site update?
- Win7 with Chrome 24.0.1312.57

Comment: This is a test comment. Edit1 Edit2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recent change accidentally caused all throttled AJAX requests to get a `200 OK` response. Comment submission throttling is one of those places where this broke things, since the JavaScript expects throttle (or any kind of failure) results to have an error status code.

Fixed now.