# Too-frequent-comment error message is showing wrong

Tags: bug, user-interface, error-message

I didn't do anything abnormal here, except comment twice too quickly.

[image]

Chrome. OS X.

At first I thought it was a nerdy joke. But I guess it was a bug.

Comment: can you show link please

Comment: Confirming. Just tried it here and it gives that.

Comment: looks like a bug or so changed the way to show message like other modification   .. but it  [give same result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/5pf0W.png)

Comment: Testing this on the mobile version of SE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confirming. Just tried it here and the bug appears as described. It seems to be overwriting the entire div containing the comment thread with some JSON, I assume returned from the AJAX query.

[image: Broken]

## Related

There seem to be some other UI bugs, presumably with the same root cause (tested in the Meta sandbox):

- When upvoting 2 comments in rapid succession, previously a message saying to wait 5 seconds would pop up. Now no message appears (nothing at all seems to happen when clicking on the 2nd comment arrow).
- Delete button does nothing (with no message) when deleting your comment immediately after upvoting another comment. (Probably the same as previous, since self-deletions are considered comment votes?)

## Update

This had the same cause as [When trying to edit comments quick, error message pops up wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166409/when-trying-to-edit-comments-quick-error-message-pops-up-wrong), [which is now fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166434/146243).